# Reading a file in QPython for android

Tags: android, binary, qpython

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:console
#qpy:2

import pickle
ifile=open("marks.dat", "wb")
l1=["stu1", "English", "87"]
l2=["stu2", "maths", "99"]
pickle.dump(l1, ifile)
pickle.dump(l2, ifile)
ifile.close()

ofile=open("marks.dat", "rb")
pickle.load(ofile)
pickle.load(ofile)
ofile.close()
```

The first three commented lines of code ensure that the program is run in QPython console mode and that it executes input and raw input statements properly.

I'm having a problem reading data from the binary file I created using the code. Here's the error message:

IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'marks.dat'

I'm not an experienced programmer. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file with a attribute(append)
Like this:

```
ofile=open('marks.dat', 'a')
```

Also check that your file is located on qpython scripts dir.
In case Android 4.4(KitKat) they have write protection to SDCard, google for SDFix for KitKat.

Good Luck.

Comment: It appears we have to root our device http://www.frandroid.com/applications/201161_sdfix-kitkat-android-root . Someone have another solution ? I'm in same situation...